# PHP Checking Date Past

Tags: php

I am using RFC822 date format and trying to get my if statement to work however it will not and I cant work out why, this is what the data is echoing as:

```
$currentdate = Fri, 01 Mar 13 22:24:02 +0000
$post['created_on'] = Sat, 17 Nov 2012 19:26:46 +0100
```

This is my statement:

```
$currentdate = date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime("-7 days"));
if ($post['created_on'] < $currentdate) 
{
  echo "test";
}
else
{

}
```

I am trying to check if the array created on is within the last 7 days, I assume its something to do with the "<" in the statement or the way the date is formated?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: You're comparing strings, not dates.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare timestamps:

```
<?php
if (strtotime($post['created_on']) >= strtotime('-7 days'))
{
    // Created in the last seven days
}
```

Comment: This will not work with daylight saving times. Twice a year you'll have bugs. **use DateTime for that**

Answer (score 0):

You code cannot work as you doing an alphanumerical comparison. RFC822 is not designed for that.

Note that `Fri ...` is lower than `Sat ...` is such comparison as `F` comes before `S` in alphabet.

Use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$currentdate = new DateTime('-7days +0100'); // ! use the same tz offset as the post !
$postdate = new DateTime('Sat, 17 Nov 2012 19:26:46 +0100');

if($postdate < $currentdate) {
  // ... do stufff
}
```